# Can I 'Add Document' of type URL to my Collection?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-discovery

I want to index a website into my collection, essentially I want to index my Wordpress website, by looping through all the posts' URLs.

E.g.

```
url=http://www.szirine.com/blog/2016/02/07/anne-dunn/
```

Ofcourse, ideally I would want to be able to iteratively index a whole domain or URI,
E.g.

```
url=http://www.szirine.com/
url=http://www.szirine.com/blog/
```

Answer (score 2):

The best solution at present is to use Data Crawler, available on the Discovery Service dashboard in Bluemix.

Data Crawler as of v1.3.0 *does not* have a native way to crawl websites over HTTP or HTTPS. This may change in a future version of Data Crawler.

For now, though, it is possible to mimic a web crawl by using [GNU
wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/), a widely available HTTP client with a mirroring mode and [great
documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html), to download a website locally and upload it to Discovery Service using Data Crawler's filesystem connector.

To mirror a website, use `wget --mirror http://www.example.com`. For more information, please read the above-linked documentation.

If native web crawling is something that you very much want, open a ticket so that we can understand how strong of a demand there is for this feature.

One note: [wget for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) exists but is not very valuable at the moment because Data Crawler does not support Windows as of v1.3.0.

Comment: where is the Data Crawler?  I can't seem to find it on the dashboard.

Comment: It is a little… buried, unfortunately. Go to https://console.ng.bluemix.net/dashboard/apps and click on Discovery in the list of services at the bottom. If you've not already created an instance of Discovery Service for yourself, you'll need to do so with the "Create Service" button. On the dashboard for your instance of Discovery Service, look for the "Intended Use" section. The download links for Data Crawler are in that paragraph.

Comment: Thanks Colin. Not what I was hoping for as I still have to loop through the individual scraped html files. The wget command and the crawler work to get the web pages. In this case, it's a WordPress site, so I can use the WP REST API, which is even easier: GET /wp-json/wp/v2/posts to get the JSON.